# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 using or in query

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I am getting error when adding loop != "" in my sql query

```
    $DuplicateCheck='select * from acpass where acno= :cname and securtyq != 
     "" or loop != ""';

            $RsDuplicate=$connpdo->prepare($DuplicateCheck);
            $RsDuplicate->bindParam(':cname', $cname[$l], PDO::PARAM_STR);



            $RsDuplicate->execute();


        $RowS=$RsDuplicate->rowCount();
```

Comment: `$DuplicateCheck='select * from acpass where acno= :cname and (securtyq IS NOT NULL or loop IS NOT NULL) ';` ??

Comment: Would you please show us the structure of the table `acpass` ? (eventually the creation structure)

Comment: In SQL, you write `<>` and not `!=`. Also, in SQL the string delimiter is `'` and not `"`.